# Looking to write out to separate files; Python:

Tags: python, file, text, split

I'm looking to get the queryvars to write out to separate files. I have looked into it and I am pretty sure I need to move it to another file and import it to that file. I am very open to suggestions:

```
def nestForLoop():
    lines = open("ampersand_right_split.txt", 'r').readlines()
    f = open("newfile3.txt".format(), 'w')
    for l in lines:
        if "&" in l:
            #param, value = str.split("?",1)
            mainurl,_, query = l.partition('?')
            queryvars = query.split("&")
            if len(l) == 0:
                break
            print l
            f.write(l)
    f.close()   

nestForLoop()
```

Comment: Please use spaces when formatting Python code (it helps preventing indent errors like your post has). Also, I don't really understand *what* you are asking.

Comment: How would I be able to split the resulting query arguments on & chars to get different query arguments? @Wayne Werner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

à la Clippy: "It looks like you're trying to parse a URL"

From [the `urlparse` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html):

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> o = urlparse('http://www.example.com/query%28%29.cgi?somevar=thing&someothervar=otherthing')
>>> o   
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.com', path='/query%28%29.cgi', params='', query='somevar=thing&someothervar=otherthing', fragment='')
```

So, to integrate this with your example:

```
from urlparse import urlparse
def nestForLoop():
    lines = open("ampersand_right_split.txt", 'r').readlines()
    with open("newfile3.txt".format(), 'w') as f:

        for l in lines:
            url = urlparse(l)
            if url.query:
                #param, value = str.split("?",1)
                queryvars = url.query # Good to know, but why did we get this again?
                if len(l) == 0:
                    break
                print l
                f.write(l)

nestForLoop()
```

Comment: How would I be able to split the resulting query arguments on & chars to get different query arguments?

Comment: Almost couldn't decide between +1 or -1 for the Clippy reference ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
def nestForLoop():
lines = open("ampersand_right_split.txt", 'r').readlines()
f = open("newfile3.txt".format(), 'w')
g = open("newfile4.txt".format(), 'w')
for l in lines:
    if "&" in l:
        #param, value = str.split("?",1)
        mainurl,_, query = l.partition('?')
        queryvars = query.split("&")
        if len(l) == 0:
            break
        print l
        f.write(l)
        g.write(queryvars)
f.close()   
g.close()
```

Is one way to do it!